qdisc prio vs qdisc mq
I want to use qdisc prio for traffic classifying by filters. Server has 64 hardware queues.
Faced qdisc mq with fq_codel on every queue configured by default.
I've read everything I found about mq but still don't understand:
What's difference for server between configuring qdisc prio on eth0 without mq:
tc qdisc add root dev eth0 handle 1: prio

or prio for every queue:
tc qdisc add root dev eth0 handle 1: mq
tc qdisc replace dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10: prio
tc qdisc replace dev eth0 parent 1:2 handle 20: prio
...

Does it mean that in the first case all traffic will be processed by one core or what?
